# Getting IIS Application filesystem path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I have IIS 7.0 installed on and there is a .net application with a .svc service there.

I would like to point a file in the virtual directory pointed by the application (please note that I converted my virtual dir in an application).

However, when I try to open a file, using a general api call in the .net-verse, and do not specify a root (complete) path but relative, I end up in the error when a resource is not found.

How can I obtain the physical path of my app?

Note that this is a web application. It cannot use the `Request` object because it needs to make this call from the web service, hosted by my app.

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.aspx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try this might help to resolve your issue

```
string apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

or

```
string apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/folder/file");
```

Comment: I cannot add reference to these strange namespace: System.Web.Hosting... Even if I pass to asp.net 4 non client mode...

Comment: @Andry - check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a console application project template or any other template other than Web application then you have to add a reference to System.Web.

You will then be able to refer to the System.Web.Hosting namespace.

Hope this helps!