# Getting IIS Folder physical path inside a Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, iis

This question is strictly related with Windows Forms as my task is to do this inside a SAP Business one addon using C#. My requirement is to alter some configuration values stored in a Web.Config file of a related wcf service hosted in IIS. I need to get the IIS folder path (even the default path could be like "C:\inetpub\wwwroot", looking for a way to get it without hard-coding it) inside the SAP B1 form (Think as inside of a Windows Forms).

I've tried out the suggestion posted in the [Getting IIS Application filesystem path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334992/getting-iis-application-filesystem-path) thread.

```
string apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

Even if I added the System.Web reference to the project it gives me a null value, and I cant add the System.Web reference specifically to address this issue.

Also I've found Environment.SpecialFolder enum usage on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) but even it doesn't list IIS physical folder.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System))
```

Can someone suggest a workaround for this scenario? Even getting this value from the system registry would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the web application configuration information from IIS. That means you will need a library such as Microsoft.Web.Administration from Microsoft (part of IIS),

https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration

or its open source equivalent from Jexus Manager,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration.Jexus